# Can I clean the repl?

Tags: clojure, read-eval-print-loop

I have played with a lot of code in a repl console, how can I clear it? I would like a fresh one without restarting it. Can that be done?

Answer (score 54):

If you want to clear the current namespace of all temporary variables and functions you declared you can use this one liner (or make a function of it) :

```
(map #(ns-unmap *ns* %) (keys (ns-interns *ns*)))
```

or

```
(ns myutil)
(defn ns-clean
       "Remove all internal mappings from a given name space or the current one if no parameter given."
   ([] (ns-clean *ns*)) 
   ([ns] (map #(ns-unmap ns %) (keys (ns-interns ns)))))
(ns mytest)

... make loads of junk ...

(myutil/ns-clean)

... great!!! I can now make all new junk ...
```

It does not claim to give you a squeaky clean namespace, just one with less of the junk which usually accumulates in a typical repl session.

Use with caution : do not pull the rug from under your feet!

Comment: thanks. i was thinking about just getting rid of the text in the console... you put new light into it

Comment: This is an amazing answer in search of the right question.

Answer (score 25):

If you are running the repl through a terminal window (eg: Terminal.app on MacOS or xterm/aterm/urxvt etc on linux) then you can type **Control-L** and it should clear the terminal window and give you a new repl prompt. However all macros/atoms you previously defined are still going to be in memory, so this is just a "Cosmetic" clear.

Comment: the initial question was about cosmetically clearing the repl. later i realized that clearing could also mean something else :)

Answer (score 19):

In EMACS/slime REPLs
C-c C-o clears the last output (in case you've typed something that gave a very long answer)
C-c M-o clears the whole thing

In GNOME terminals, you've got a menu option Terminal/Reset and Clear

Comment: Note that C-c M-o does not erase any work actually interpreted by the REPL already, it just clears the screen. Any definitions are still there.

Answer (score 7):

The shorcut to clean the whole buffer : <kbd>C</kbd>-<kbd>u</kbd> <kbd>C</kbd>-<kbd>c</kbd> <kbd>C</kbd>-<kbd>o</kbd>

The shortcut to clean the last output : <kbd>C</kbd>-<kbd>c</kbd> <kbd>C</kbd>-<kbd>o</kbd>

Note, the old way was : <kbd>C</kbd>-<kbd>c</kbd> <kbd>M</kbd>-<kbd>o</kbd>

Also, `cider-repl-clear-buffer` (which is bound to <kbd>C</kbd>-<kbd>ENTER</kbd> <kbd>s</kbd>-<kbd>c</kbd> on my machine)

Answer (score 4):

If you are using Emacs + [`nREPL`](https://github.com/clojure/tools.nrepl), you can either:

- Run <kbd>M</kbd><kbd>x</kbd> `nrepl-clear-buffer` *or*
- Run <kbd>C</kbd><kbd>c</kbd> <kbd>M</kbd><kbd>o</kbd>

If the key binding is not enabled, run <kbd>M</kbd><kbd>x</kbd>`nrepl-interaction-mode` to enable it. You can find other useful shortcuts in [nrepl.el](https://github.com/kingtim/nrepl.el/blob/v0.1.7/nrepl.el#L1506) and/or customize the key bindings to fit your needs.

*Note: you can find all `nREPL`'s key bindings in your system by running `M-x v` `nrepl-mode-map` and following the `nrepl.el` link.*

Answer (score 2):

I use the Emacs command `cider-repl-clear-buffer` via <kbd>M-x</kbd>. One might also use `cider-repl-clear-output` with a prefix argument: <kbd>C-u C-c C-o</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

It depends what you mean by 'clean'. To remove all namespaces within a 'package' you can use:

```
(mapv remove-ns 
  (map symbol 
    (filter #(.startsWith % "org.mycompany") 
      (map str (all-ns)))))
```

Answer (score 0):

For users of the Cursive IDE plugin for IntelliJ IDEA who end up here, like me:

You can "cosmetically" clear the REPL (keeping your def'd symbols etc.) by clicking on this icon at the top of the REPL frame:

[image: Clear REPL icon]

There's no default key binding for this, but you can easily add one by opening your preferences, navigating to Keymap > Plugins > Cursive, and adding a binding for "Clear output for current REPL".

Alternatively, you can right-click in the editor and access "Clear output for current REPL" via the REPL commands.