# Possible to reset user environment in Scheme REPL?

Tags: lisp, scheme, reset, read-eval-print-loop

Scheme newbie question-

Is there a way for me to reset my current REPL environment (i.e. the default user environment) without quitting and restarting my REPL? Basically I'd like a way to wipe out my current environment so that none of my previous defines are in effect. This is using GNU/MIT Scheme.

If this is impossible, what's the best practice here when just messing around with code in the REPL? I've heard people talk about creating and deleting packages, but most examples seem to be for Common Lisp which is a bit different.

I did find information on how to do this in the Clojure REPL but there were caveats and it seems like it's Clojure-specific: [Can I clean the repl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3636364/can-i-clean-the-repl)

Thanks!

Edit: I'm able to accomplish functionally the same thing by quitting and restarting the REPL process itself. I found a way to do this but keep the connection to my editor (vim) alive using vim-screen. This is an acceptable solution if there's no way to do it from within the REPL. However, I'll keep the question open a bit longer to see if there's a way to do this inside the language as I think it will be instructive.

Comment: Would it work for you to just stop the REPL and start it again?

Comment: Yep, but I prefer the solution given below since I can keep that expression in my text buffer and send it to the REPL without leaving my editor, whereas restarting the REPL requires me to actually switch focus to its window, run the quit command, and then invoke a new REPL which takes longer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think that this is implementation specific, but in MIT Scheme you can clear the REPL environment with:

```
1 ]=> (ge (make-top-level-environment))
```

The function `(ge [environment])` "Changes the current REP loop environment to [environment]."  and the function `make-top-level-environment` "returns a newly allocated top-level environment".

MIT Scheme has a bunch of environment-management functions that you can peruse [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/mit-scheme/documentation/mit-scheme-ref/Environment-Operations.html)

I tested this on Mac OS X (10.6.7) with MIT Scheme 9.0.1 installed via the pre-built binary from the GNU site, with the following REPL session:

```
1 ]=> (define foo 1)

;Value: foo

1 ]=> foo

;Value: 1

1 ]=> (ge (make-top-level-environment))

;Value 13: #[environment 13]

1 ]=> foo

;Unbound variable: foo
;To continue, call RESTART with an option number:
; (RESTART 3) => Specify a value to use instead of foo.
; (RESTART 2) => Define foo to a given value.
; (RESTART 1) => Return to read-eval-print level 1.

2 error>
```

I think that different implementations have different conventions but I don't think there's anything quite like Common Lisp's packages. If you're not wedded to MIT Scheme, you should check out Racket and Dr Racket, which is a nice IDE that might be more powerful than a plain REPL at the command line, and I think it has some kind of module system. Racket is its own dialect of Scheme, so depending on what you're doing, it might not be appropriate. (the default language module in Racket is not the same as MIT Scheme)

I've struggled with all this recently (past few months) when I went looking for a Scheme that could run the code from Lisp in Small Pieces, which has a bunch of weird macros. Gambit ended up being the best bet. If you don't have a need like this though, check out Racket.

Comment: I had perused this documentation before and it was still unclear to me how to accomplish what I'm trying to do. The procedure above appears to work, but it only works once and can have some dangerous side effects.

What it does is switch the current environment to the system-global environment. After that, any defines I make take effect in the global environment. Additionally, the REPL is now in a more dangerous mode as I can redefine standard procedures globally.

What I'd like to do is create a brand new environment that is a child of the system-global-environment, and then switch to it.

Comment: I'm using MIT Scheme because I'm following along with the MIT OpenCourseware class 6.001 http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-001-structure-and-interpretation-of-computer-programs-spring-2005/ and it is the Lisp dialect in use by the text and current students of the course. Racket looks interesting... can I treat it as equivalent to MIT-Scheme and ignore the other functionality of it until I need it later?

Comment: There's a Racket SICP package, but you can also see what other people have suggested on SO regarding this particular combination, which has come up before: http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=racket+sicp+site%3Astackoverflow.com

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean about "dangerous side effects", can you give an example? I'm able to redefine `car`, `cdr`, etc at the top-level of a fresh REPL, without having mucked with the environments.

Comment: You could also try `(ge (make-top-level-environment))` but I don't know what the difference is.

Comment: I think switching to the global environment circumvents this: "Although all bindings in system-global-environment are visible to the REP loop, definitions that are typed at, or loaded by, the REP loop occur in the user-initial-environment. This is partly a safety measure: if you enter a definition that happens to have the same name as a critical system procedure, your definition will be visible only to the procedures you define in the user-initial-environment; the MIT/GNU Scheme system procedures, which are defined in system-global-environment, will continue to see the original definition."

Comment: `(ge (make-top-level-environment))` appears to be what I was looking for. It makes a new environment under the system environment and then switches to it! All my previous defines are no longer effect in this new environment, and I can use it repeatedly. Feel free to post this as a new answer or add it into your current answer and I'll accept it!

The difference is that `(ge system-global-environment)` switches to the system global environment, so defines there take effect across all procedures, and you can't run that command again to reset your defines, it only works once.